# Importing Autodesk.AutoCAD in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, autocad, autodesk, autocad-plugin

For my project, I need to generate CAD drawing (almost a blueprint of a tank) through my VB.NET application. The app takes in some user input & based on this, it generates the geometry of the tank.

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 & coding in the VB.NET language.

I have browsed through a lot of AutoCAD documentation but could not find exactly how & where are the modules hidden, for me to add them into my code.

[I stumbled accross one particular document](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer%27s%20Guide/index.html?url=WS73099cc142f48755-385a98b0121d1bb015f-300c.htm,topicNumber=d0e7688)
 which is where I found how to add the relevant files as reference to my VB solution. However, after adding some particular files I could then do `Imports AutoCAD`, but all the docs show that I must use `Autodesk.AutoCAD`. On inspection of the available modules/methods of the `Imports AutoCAD` I can see that it isn't complete as needed for the application development.

Can somebody please guide me as to how could I find or go about adding correct reference files to my VS solution to get full functionality from the AutoCAD modules? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted this quite some time ago. It contains the information that you need

[How to close a file in Autocad using C# keeping acad.exe running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741728/how-to-close-a-file-in-autocad-using-c-sharp-keeping-acad-exe-running/17757356#17757356)

You can also download any of the AutoCAD .NET API's from here:

http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?id=1911627&siteID=123112

Just in case someone else need the help.

1. Download the appropriate AutoCAD .NET API using the aforementioned link.
2. Put them in a location of your choosing.

---

***general:***

---

on the appropriate project in your visual studio's solution, right click -> Add Reference.

select Browse on left, click the browse button and go to the path where you saved the ObjectARX download.

---

***Inprocess:***

---

Navigate to the inc directory and
select the `AcDbMgd.dll` and `AcMgd.dll` then click add.

***For these make sure to set the copy local property to false.***

---

***Interop:***

---

Navigate to the appropriate directory: inc-win32 or inc-x64 depending on your processor. 
select the `Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.dll` and `Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.dll` then click add.

---

and unless you have an interest in the AutoCAD interface don't worry about the AcCui.dll

Hope this helps some one out :)

Answer (score 0):

So, looking up more & more documentation led me to [stumble across this](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20.NET%20Developer%27s%20Guide/index.html)

I found the dlls by simple file search for respective dlls metioned below in my local AutoCAD 2014 installation folder (C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2014)

As per the documentation, following dlls are important ones -

1. AcCui.dll
2. acdbmgd.dll
3. acmgd.dll
4. Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.dll
5. Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop.Common.dll

The credit for the last 2 dlls goes to Trae Moore.

How to add references to the dlls was mentioned in the documentation link.

Comment: Updated. i posted the link where you can download any of the .NET API's from autocad.