# Using inprocess assemblies in IronPython? - AutoCAD

Tags: .net, api, dll, ironpython, autocad

I'm having a couple of issues referencing some assemblies using IronPython so i can import the namespaces to read/edit a CAD file using the AutoCAD API.

I can add reference and import the Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop assembly just fine, but for some reason I can't add the acdbmgd.dll, acmgd.dll, accoremgd.dll or the AecBaseMgd.dll.

It could have something to do with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17741728/how-to-close-a-file-in-autocad-using-c-sharp-keeping-acad-exe-running/17757356#17757356):

***"AutoCAD does have an api. there are 4 assemblys. Two for in-process and two for COM.***

***inprocess : acdbmgd.dll acmgd.dll***

***COMInterop : Autodesk.Autocad.Interop.dll Autodesk.Autocad.Interop.Common.dll"***

The [Autodesk developers guide](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-civil-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/Civil3D-DevGuide/files/GUID-DE3A46DA-508E-43A0-8538-C77D978D06B2-htm.html) states:

*Browse to the install directory for AutoCAD Civil 3D, and select the base libraries acdbmgd.dll, acmgd.dll, accoremgd.dll, AecBaseMgd.dll, and AeccDbMgd.dll.
Note:
These are the base AutoCAD and AutoCAD Civil 3D managed libraries. Your .NET assembly can use classes defined in additional libraries.*

I'm guessing the inprocess is the issue? I just don't know why.

Here is my code:

The error: **IOError: [Errno 127] A procedure imported by 'acdbmgd.dll' could not be loaded.**

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016')
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016\C3D')

import clr
#Add standard AutoCAD References
clr.AddReferenceToFile('acdbmgd.dll')
clr.AddReferenceToFile('acmgd.dll')
clr.AddReferenceToFile('accoremgd.dll')
clr.AddReferenceToFile('AecBaseMgd.dll')

#Add Civil Reference
clr.AddReferenceToFile('AeccDbMgd.dll')

#AutoCad namespaces
import Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime
import Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices
import Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices
import Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput

#Civil namespaces
import Autodesk.Civil
import Autodesk.Civil.ApplicationServices
```

### EDIT:

Thanks to Hans Passant, just a version issue. Now another issue:

The standard Autocad files have imported, but trying to import the civil one (AeccDbMgd.dll) spits out this error:

***IOError: [Errno 2] Could not load file or assembly 'AeccDbMgd.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.***

Thanks to everyone who read this! I appreciate your time.

Cheers,

TJ

Comment: Error 127 is always a versioning issue, the unmanaged equivalent of MissingMethodException.

Comment: Brill thanks for that, didn't realise I wasn't running the same version! The standard Autocad files have imported, but the civil one (AeccDbMgd.dll) won't for some reason.
IOError: [Errno 2] Could not load file or assembly 'AeccDbMgd.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
Apparantly that's normally a directory error, so i edited the code:

clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r'C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016\C3D\AeccDbMgd.dll')